# Does every large project include a Lisp interpreter?

Tags: c++, c, lisp, project-management

I had the impression that there was a paper or article somewhere that claimed every sufficiently large project (not written in a Lisp variant) contained a poorly implemented Lisp interpreter.  Google turns up nothing and a quick search of SO doesn't either.  Is this something well known and documented somewhere I have forgotten, or just a figment of my imagination?

An actual document or link to such an article would be appreciated, if it exists.  Otherwise, I will remove the question.

Comment: check out this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule)

Comment: This is a great question for programmers.SE, a poor one for SO.

Comment: Could someone move this question to programmers.SE?  Regards to  @bitmask

Comment: Here's my rule: Every sufficiently interesting question on stackoverflow is doom to be closed by an ad-hoc, poorly organized, bug obsessed cadre of half witted lisp haters.

Comment: @ergosys: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette -- And just for the record, I think Lisp is a great idea. And to reiterate: This is an awesome question, but if there is to be any meaningful separation between the SE sites, it should be moved to the appropriate place.

Comment: @bitmask, I don't see any thing being moved. But even so, I don't see much meaning in the seperation(s) in the first place.  It's an entirely pointless waste of everyone's time to try to put the vast web of interelated programming topics into neat little silo-ed up categories.   And if I offended any lisp haters, honestly I didn't mean to, it was just an attempt at humor.

Comment: @ergosys: No offence taken here! Anyway, I'm not saying it's a perfect system, but it happens to be community consensus. Regarding the move: I would, but I believe it requires divine (i.e. moderator) intervention to move a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this claim is [Greenspun's tenth rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule) (actually the only rule):

> Any sufficiently complicated C or Fortran program contains an ad hoc,
>   informally-specified, bug-ridden, slow implementation of half of
>   Common Lisp.

It is making a valid point about the expressiveness of Lisp-style features (particularly its kind of macros).  However, it isn't serious to the degree you would write a paper on it.

Comment: 'Yes' meaning 'no', as not every large project literally includes a Lisp interpreter...

Comment: @ildjarn: "Yes" meaning "Yes", as in "yes, he did claim that" (even though I agree he was wrong).

Comment: @Jerry : I took it as a 'yes' to `Does every large project include a Lisp interpreter?`. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Actually, the phenomenon is quite real and I bet you could write a paper on it. Just find half a dozen mainstream C projects which contain instances of badly re-implemented Lisp features in disguise, and write up your findings into a little exposee.

Answer (score 5):

What Greenspun meant when he uttered this quip was that Lisp provides a great many foundational technologies for writing good software, and that programs written in other languages informally (and inferiorly) reproduce a number of them as they grow.